# Find the real parameters m and n such that the graph of the function f : R → R, $f(x) = \sqrt[3]{8x^3 + mx^2}− nx$ has the horizontal asymptote y=1

Tags: calculus, limits

Find the real parameters m and n such that the graph of the function f : R → R,
$f(x) = \sqrt[3]{8x^3 + mx^2}− nx$
has the horizontal asymptote y=1

I think this question could be solved if we show that the limit when x tends to infinity equals 1.
The graph of this function is not easy to visualize and moreover, how can I show what I just stated?

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see the [guidelines for good use of $\rm\LaTeX$ in question titles](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730).

Comment: @soupless Title Added

Comment: If $m < 0$, then as $x \to +\infty$, the first term will approach $(2x)$ from below.  Therefore, to have the overall expression approach a finite value, as $x \to +\infty, ~n$ must equal $2$.  Then, the trick is to find $m$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $y=1$ is an asymptote of the given curve, we must have $$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=1$$

$$\Rightarrow \lim_{x\to\infty} \sqrt[3]{8x^3 + mx^2}−nx=1$$

Substituting $x=\frac1t$ where $t\to0$, we get

$$\lim_{t\to0} \frac{\sqrt[3]{8+mt}}{t}−\frac nt=1$$

$$\Rightarrow \lim_{t\to0} \frac{\sqrt[3]{8+mt}-n}{t}=1$$

Since this limit is finite but the denominator tends to $0$, we must have this limit of the form $\frac00$ so that we can expect the limit to be finite. So,

$$\sqrt[3]{8+m(0)}-n=0$$

$$\Rightarrow n=2$$

Now, we can use the value of the limit to evaluate $m$. Therefore,

$$\Rightarrow \lim_{t\to0} \frac{\sqrt[3]{8+mt}-2}{t}=1$$

$$\lim_{t\to0} \frac{8+mt-2^3}{t\left[(8+mt)^\frac23+n^2+n\sqrt[3]{8+mt}\right]}=1$$

$$\frac{m}{12}=1$$

$$\Rightarrow m=12$$

Comment: Perfect explanation. Could you just explain how you simplified the last limit?

Comment: @mathx we can observe that the numerator reduces to $mt$ and we have a single $t$ in the denominator. So, they cancel each other and the $\frac00$ form is eliminated from the limit. Then it's just substituting $t=0$ in the remaining.

Comment: RiverX15 first used the $(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)=a^3-b^3$ identity, then things simplify:
$$ \require{cancel}
\lim_{t\to0} \frac{\cancel{8}+m\bcancel{t}-\cancel{2^3}}{\bcancel{t}\left[\underbrace{(8+mt)^\frac23}_{\to 8^\frac23=4}+\underbrace{n^2}_{=2^2=4}+\underbrace{n\sqrt[3]{8+mt}}_{\to 2\cdot 8^\frac13=4}\right]}=1
$$